# Modify Controllers (Dependency Injection) in Smart-Store.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, autofac, nopcommerce

I want to modify some Controllers for which i need to add few more parameters to the Constructor of the Controller. If I add more parameters, it won't work. Can you please suggest where do I need to map the parameters (for ioc) so that it works fine?

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean?  Also, show some code.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to implement the [IControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory.aspx) interface, particularly the `GetControllerInstance` method. Often, the easiest way to do that is to derive from [DefaultControllerfactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx).

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
    RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == typeof(FooController))
    {
        return new FooController(new BarService(), new BazProvider());
    }
    if (controllerType == typeof(QuxController))
    {
        return new QuxController(new QuuxRepository, new CorgeProvider());
    }
    // etc.
    return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
}
```

Then you need to tell ASP.NET MVC about your new custom factory:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyCustomControllerFactory());
```

You can read more details about this in chapter 7 in [my book](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236).